# Wix - Superseding patches doesn't do anything

Tags: wix, patch

I've seen many questions like this one asked but I've found none with my particular problem that has been answered. I'm using purely wix to build minor upgrades for a product.

This question is an example which is much like my scenario, except for the last part.

I have a product for which I build an X4.0.1.0.msi file, 
Contains A.config and many other files
I then build a patch called X4.0.2.0.msp which uses Product-1.0 as it's baseline
updates and adds some files
I then build a patch called X4.0.3.0.msp which also uses Product-1.0 as it's baseline
updates and adds some files.
This means that my patches will always contain the preceding fixes and supersede each other.
Scenarios:

4.0.1 -> 4.0.2 Works fine
4.0.1 -> 4.0.3 Works fine
4.0.1 -> 4.0.2 -> 4.0.3 Doesn't work(In this case there is no change came from 4.0.3.0)

ProductCode is unchanged.
UpgradeCode is unchanged.

This snippet is from my patch 1 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

<Patch AllowRemoval="yes" Classification="Update" Comments="Cincom Guru 4.0 Service Pack 1" Description="Cincom Guru 4.0 Service Pack 1"
DisplayName="Cincom Guru 4.0 Service Pack 1" Manufacturer="Cincom Systems, Inc." TargetProductName="Cincom Guru 4.0" Id="{patch guid}">

<Media Id="5000" Cabinet="CincomGuruPatch.cab">

<PatchBaseline Id="CincomGuruPatch" />
</Media>
    <PatchFamily
    Id="ServicePack1"
    Version="0.0.0.1"
    ProductCode="productguid"
    Supersede="yes">
    </PatchFamily>

</Patch>

</Wix>
```

for patch 2 i just changed version for product 4.0.1.0 to 4.0.2.0 for patch 1
4.0.1.0 to 4.0.3.0 for patch 2
Please provide a working solution.

Thanks

Comment: In the verbose installer log generated at the time of installing patch 4.0.3.0, do you see SELMGR  traces, which indicate that some feature is advertised?  Search for the keyword "advertised". If 4.0.3.0 is supposed to supersede 4.0.2.0, it should contain all the changes contained in 4.0.2.0 such as any component added in 4.0.2.0. I suspect 4.0.3.0 doesnt currently contain the changes introduced in 4.0.2.0 as your base package has been 4.0.1.0 and hence your upgrade path 4.0.1.0 --> 4.0.2.0 --> 4.0.3.0 does not work. Let me know what you see in your log files and we can take this forward.

Comment: Thanks for your help...
but after a bit of my research , i was missing some validation checks like below in patchbaseline tag.
   '  <PatchBaseline Id="CincomGuruPatch" >
      <Validate ProductVersion="Minor" UpgradeCode="yes" ProductId="yes"/>
     </PatchBaseline>'

Comment: Interesting. I am wondering how would these validation checks make a difference in only  the upgrade path 4.0.1 --> 4.0.2 --> 4.0.3 but why not with 4.0.1--> 4.0.2  or 4.0.1 --> 4.0.3.

Comment: Firstly i was also wondering that these checks are making the difference. but after sometime i found that by default it checks for the target version from which we create difference.wixmst file and if we explicitly mention which part of the version is changed then only it checks for that particular version (like here minor).

Correct me if I am wrong.